# Custom python package intellisense in VScode not working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pygame, intellisense

When I am working with any standard module like `random` ,`collections` and so on auto complete feature of vscode is working fine. But when I installed another packages like `pygame` the autocomplete feature is not working.

Like as can be seen in the    image. `.set_mode()` in not in the auto complete list 
[image: win = pygame.display.set_mode()]

I have already tried adding the `"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["C:\\Users\\Aman\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\Lib\\site-packages"]` to the **settings.json** file.

Answer (score 0):

There are some open issues in github but for the moment, we can't use intellicode properly in vscode.

The issuses:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7278
https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/1393

Let's pray for the fix

***EDIT***

Use kite instead its an autocomplete plugin for vscode (and others) that works very well
link: https://kite.com/